# PainlessDictionary for painless debugging

Tags: c#, hash-map

While working with dictionaries I've been always running into the same two problems (who wasn't?):

- The indexer throws the `KeyNotFoundExcepion` if you try to retrieve an item with a non-existing key that does not tell you which key is missing.
- The `Add` method throws the `ArgumentExcetpion` if you try to add an item with the same key and it also does not contain the key name.

There is also a secondary problem: there is no constructor accepting any `IEnumerable`s so every time you create a dictionary from something non-dictionary you often end up looping twice twice over a collection (expecially with types derived from a dictionary) - and you cannot easily work with tuples.

I tried to *fix* it with my own implementation that is built on top of the *normal* dictionary. It adds two `try/catch`es to add the key to the message and it adds `IEnumerable` constructors.

```
public class PainlessDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

    public static readonly IEqualityComparer<TKey> DefaultComparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

    public PainlessDictionary()
    : this(DefaultComparer)
    { }

    public PainlessDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer);
    }

    public PainlessDictionary(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source)
    : this(source, DefaultComparer)
    { }

    public PainlessDictionary(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    : this(comparer)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }        

    public PainlessDictionary(IEnumerable<(TKey Key, TValue Value)> source)
        : this(source, DefaultComparer)
    { }

    public PainlessDictionary(IEnumerable<(TKey Key, TValue Value)> source, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    : this(comparer)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _dictionary[key];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"The '{key}' key was not present in the dictionary", ex);
            }
        }
        set => _dictionary[key] = value;
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys => _dictionary.Keys;

    public ICollection<TValue> Values => _dictionary.Values;

    public int Count => _dictionary.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => _dictionary.IsReadOnly;

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        try
        {
            _dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The '{key}' key has already been added.", ex);
        }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) => Add(item.Key, item.Value);

    public void Clear() => _dictionary.Clear();

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) => _dictionary.Contains(item);

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex) => _dictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() => _dictionary.GetEnumerator();

    public bool Remove(TKey key) => _dictionary.Remove(key);

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) => _dictionary.Remove(item);

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) => _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _dictionary.GetEnumerator();

    public IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary() => new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(_dictionary);

}
```

There is nothing fancy about it so no examples this time. The question is as usual: is there anything (terribly) wrong with this class or maybe there is something missing? Is there anything that could be done better to make debugging even easier?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your description, but I was expecting the `Add` method not to throw an exception but rather to silently replace the value for a duplicate key.  Then again you could create a new `AddOrReplace` method for that.

Comment: @RickDavin adding a new method (or even better, an extension) is actually a good idea. I wouldn't however change the behaviour of `Add` as this is how you expect it to work.

Comment: But in the question you state throwing an exception is a problem

Comment: @Paparazzi right, one part of the sentence got lost in editing. Fixed.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by looping twice over an enumerable, but would the `.ToDictionary()` extension help with that?

Comment: @BenAaronson if you have a custom type that is derived from a dictionary and you want to create it from another collection then you always have to either create a dictionary twice - first with `ToDictionary` to pass it to the constructor, then the base constructor runs another loop or you have to write you own constructor that supports enumerables which is kind of painful to do everytime, I find.

Comment: @RickDavin Note that the indexer already has the `AddOrReplace` behaviour (it was years before I realised this, so I don't know how common the knowledge is!). As t3chb0t says, `Add` should throw as it has always done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have much to say about the code as it's rather simple and not much can be changed on most places, but I will give my two cents.

Besides the fact that you can add some extra info in the exception message, I don't see much benefit from using this class :/

---

The constructors are better off as extension methods as you can use your constructor only in your class, but you can use the extension method on any `IDictionary<,>` type. You currently don't offer any abstraction that you can inherit to fix that. But if you do, you wont be able to force the try/catch block's extra message.

---

Printing `{key}` doesn't look really useful to me, unless you're hardcoding those values that is. I assume you're not, so probably `nameof(key)` would be better?

---

You might also want to extract the logic for adding all elements from `IEnumerable<>` into a separate method, you might even publicly expose it, not sure about that tho.

Comment: Let me try to explain the idea with different words. I pretty often use types derived from the `Dictionary` and there is no way to create them from an `IEnumerable` from a query without creating two dictionaries. You end up with one that comes from `ToDictionary` and then you pass it to the base ctor and it loops over it again. About the `key`. It's not a hardcoded string ;-) It's an interpolated string. The code actually will do `key.ToString()` because I want to know which key is missing or already added - finding this key isn't usually easy ;-]

Comment: Although know when I think of it again, an extension could also work and do the `try/catch` internally... I think I'll write it like `ToDictionary<TKey, TValue, TDic>() where T : IDicitonary<TKey, TValue> new()` and it should do too - oh, a lot of generics. This would at least work in cases where I cannot use this type because the indexer is still not covered. You try to retrieve a key that does not exist and you can debug for hours ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t I don't understand what you mean by `there is no way to create them from an IEnumerable from a query without creating two dictionaries`. `ToDictionary` is O(n) operation, it uses a single loop over the IEnumerable collection, where the 2 functors are invoked to get the key and value respectively, yours isn't much different right? You also don't accept any predicates and this is a bit restricting. What I meant about the hardcoded values, is that I'm not sure how you're going to know **where** the problem is, unless you know where you pass the exact value.

Comment: Suppose you have a class like this `class Log : Dictionary<string, object>`, now in order to initialize it from a collection you need to either write a new `ToDictionary` extension or a custom constructor running a loop from an enumerable or you end up calling the base constructor taking an `IDictionary` which leaves you with two loops over the same collection.

Comment: If I now try to put the key `Category` in this dictionary and the exception tells me that `Category` already exists there, then I have a much better idea what went wrong and which key I tried to add multiple times. Knowing that **some** key already exists isn't of any help at all ;-) I want to know the exact key.

Comment: @t3chb0t Let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67812/painlessdictionary-for-painless-debugging-discussion-with-t3chb0t-and-denis)

Answer (score 0):

I broke it down to extensions that now provide the additional `try/catch`es that add the `key` to the message. So it's possible to use them with any `IDictionary`.

```
public static TDictionary ToDictionary<TKey, TValue, TDictionary>(
    this IEnumerable<(TKey Key, TValue Value)> source,
    TDictionary target
) where TDictionary : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        target.PainlessAdd(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    return target;
}

public static TDictionary ToDictionary<TKey, TValue, TDictionary>(
    this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source,
    TDictionary target
) where TDictionary : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    return 
        source
            .Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value))
            .ToDictionary(target);
}

public static TDictionary PainlessAdd<TKey, TValue, TDictionary>(
    this TDictionary target,
    TKey key,
    TValue value
) where TDictionary : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    try
    {
        target.Add(key, value);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Dictionary key cannot be 'null'.", ex);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The '{(key == null ? "null" : key.ToString())}' key has already been added.", ex);
    }

    return target;
}

public static TValue PainlessItem<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key)
{
    try
    {
        return source[key];
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
    {
        throw new KeyNotFoundException($"The '{key}' key was not present in the dictionary", ex);
    }
}
```

Having these extensions I now could reuse them with my own dictionary. The constructors became as simple as:

```
public PainlessDictionary(IEnumerable<(TKey Key, TValue Value)> source, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
: this(comparer)
{
    source.ToDictionary(this);
}
```

and the indexer and the `Add` method are now one-liners too:

```
public TValue this[TKey key]
{
    get => _dictionary.PainlessItem(key);
    set => _dictionary[key] = value;
}

public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) => _dictionary.PainlessAdd(key, value);
```